# double integral bounded by a hyperbola

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\iint 3x^2dA$$ over the region in the first quadrant bounded by the hyperbola $$xy=9 ,y=x, y=0, x=6$$
>   (Round your answer to the nearest tenth)

can anyone show me how to set this up? I tried using (9/y to 6) and (0 to x) but These dont seem to be the right integration points. can anyone help show me how you use the hyperbole as a boundary for the double integration?

Answer (score 2):

Decompose the domain $D$ as a triangle $T=\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq 3, 0\leq y \leq x\}$ and a subgraphic
$$ S=\left\{(x,y): 3\leq x\leq 6, 0\leq y\leq\frac{9}{x}\right\}.$$
Then we have:
$$ \iint_D 3x^2\,d\mu = \iint_{T}3x^2\,d\mu+ \iint_{S}3x^2\,d\mu = \int_{0}^{3}3x^3\,dx+\int_{3}^{6}27x\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{1701}{4}}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Step: Draw the region
2. Step: Hyperbola $y=9/x$ and $y=x$ have an intersection. What is the $x$-value of this intersection? Call this value $x_0$.
3. Step: Divide the Integral into two pieces

$$\int_{x=0}^{x_0}\int_{y=0}^{x}3x^2 dy dx$$

$$\int_{x=x_0}^{6}\int_{y=0}^{9/x}3x^2 dy dx$$